# In how many ways can $3$ boys and $4$ girls sit in a row if no one sits beside a person of the same sex?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations

$3$ boys and $4$ girls have bought tickets for a row of $7$ seats at a party. In how many ways can they arrange themselves if no one sits beside a person of the same sex?

I found the answer $3! \cdot 4!$.  However, the book gives the answer  $2 \cdot 3! \cdot 4!$.  Which is correct?

Comment: How do you come up with both answers??

Comment: I thought the answer is 3! * 4!  But the book answers 2 * 3! * 4!  So I just confused.

Comment: The answer is indeed 3! * 4! as there is only one way we can arrange boys and girls { GBGBGBG }

Comment: Neither probability nor abstract algebra

Comment: Your answer is correct for the reason given by @NewGuy.

Answer (score 2):

According to Ross, there are $n!$ possible linear orderings of $n$ items (15). Since we are given that girls and boys alternate, odd-numbered positions must be occupied by girls and even-numbered positions must be occupied by boys. Thus the total number of permutations of all seven people is given by the basic principle of counting, which states that if two experiments are to be performed, where experiment 1 can result in any of $m$ possible outcomes and if, for each outcome of experiment 1, there are $n$ possible outcomes of experiment 2, then together there are $mn$ possible outcomes of the two experiments (Ross 2). If we let $m = 3!$ and we let $n = 4!$, then $mn = 3! \cdot4!$.

Work Cited 
    *Ross, Sheldon M.*, A first course in probability, Boston, MA: Pearson (ISBN 978-0-321-86681-3). ii, 454 p. (2014). [ZBL1307.60003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1307.60003).